# How to Implement IDataErrorInfo within a WPF Page (A Partial Class)

Tags: c#, wpf, idataerrorinfo

It's my first experience with WPF. And I'm developing an Inventory Management System. My design model has single Window, in which a frame loads different Pages while clicking on different buttons. While adding a new Inventory into the Database, I want to ensure Data Validation. I choose IDataErrorInfo in this regard. I have to implement the interface but unable to implement just writing as `public partial class AddInventoryPage : Page, IDataErrorInfo`. This shows error. The signature of the class is as following

```
public partial class AddInventoryPage : Page
```

I also tried as under but unable to achieve the functionality. Even I put a breakpoint within IDataErrorInfor part but the control doesn't go there.

```
namespace IMS
{
    public partial class AddInventoryPage : IDataErrorInfo
    {
    //code here
    }
    public partial class AddInventoryPage : Page
    {
    //code here
    }
}
```

As My Inventory module is completed except Data Validation, and I'm working on the Sales module; it's not a solution to change my design model. Moreover, I'm not using any Design Pattern like MVVM. It's straight.
Looking forward to a solution.

Comment: Please be more specific then "does not work". That has never been a helpfull part in a programming Forum. IIRC, most IDE's can be ordered to automatically provide empty Functions (empty save for a mandatory exception throw) for everything in a Interface. Then you just code them out.

Comment: `Moreover, I'm not using any Design Pattern like MVVM.` with WPF you probably should be. It's a steep learning curve, but it pays off once your app gets a bit of complexity

Comment: Dennis, thanks for this valuable suggestion. As I have stated, I'm not new to WPF, but I also new to C# and it's 1st time of experience to develop something other than small console protects. And till now, I have seen too much about MVVM and know it's importance now. Soon, I'm gonna shift my this project into MVVM pattern.

Comment: I have to second what Dennis Kuypers said. WPF/UWP and XAML were practically designed with the MVVM pattern in mind. While you can use any pattern, doing so misses about 90% of it's power and runs into problems at every other corner.

Answer (score 0):

example with a validation against the property 'Name'

```
public class AddInventoryPage : IDataErrorInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }       

    public string Error => null;

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            switch(columnName)
            {
                case nameof(Name):
                    if (Name == string.Empty) return "Name can not be empty";
            }

            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: example here: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/858492/WPF-Validation-Using-IDataErrorInfo